# Check if user has custom post published redirection on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to run a check when a user visits a certain page to see if the current user has a published or draft posts of a custom post type. If they do, then I'm trying to redirect them. I've found some posts, but no luck in putting it all together to fit my needs. I can understand the template redirect function a bit easier, so I've tried to go that route. I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it.

I've tried to work with these snippets:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187973/how-to-check-that-if-current-user-id-has-posts-or-not

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139818/check-if-current-user-has-post-in-post-type-and-is-author-role

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page_resume' );

    function redirect_to_specific_page_resume() {
    global $post;

    $current_user = $post->post_author;

    if(!empty($current_user)){
    $user_post_count = (int) count_user_posts( $current_user );

       if ( is_page('479') && $user_post_count == 1 ) {

            wp_redirect( "/myaccount/manage-resumes", 301 ); 

            exit;

      }
   }        
   }
```

If current user goes to PAGE ONE and is a published or draft author of a custom post type, then redirect to PAGE TWO. If current user goes to PAGE ONE and is NOT a published author of a custom post type, do nothing, load PAGE ONE as normal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by [butlerblog](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/38603/butlerblog)

```
function redirect_to_specific_page_resume() {

    /*
     * Only bother to check if the user is logged in 
     * AND we're on page ID 479. Otherwise, there's no
     * reason to run the remaining logic.
     */
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 479 ) ) {

        // Get the current logged in user's ID
        $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        // Count the user's posts for 'resume' CPT
        $user_post_count = (int) count_user_posts( $current_user_id, 'resume' );

        // If the user has a 'resume' CPT published
        if ( $user_post_count > 1 ) {

            // Get the URL to redirect the user to.
            $url = get_permalink( 480 );

            // Redirect the user.
            wp_redirect( $url ); 
            exit();

        }
    }
}
```